# how to run an sql query against all items in array php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, retrofit

My PHP script is supposed to take in an indeterminate number of JSON data from an API, store it in an array and then run SQL queries for each item in the array. Then return the queries as a JSON object.

my API looks something like this:

```
if($_POST(['id'])){
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    foreach($value as $id){
        $sql = "SELECT id, header, body FROM `messages` WHERE id= $id";
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $response = $row ['id'];
            $response = $row ['header'];
            $response = $row ['body'];
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

to me, this seems very inefficient, there has to be an SQL function to check all the variables in an array.

I need my JSON to look something like this

```
{
    "resoponse": {
        "check": "check"
    },
    "code": [{
            "id": "id",
            "header": "header",
            "body": "body"
        },
        {
            "id": "id",
            "header": "header",
            "body": "body"
        },
        {
            "id": "id",
            "header": "header",
            "body": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am returning the JSON back to an android app running kotin using retrofit/gson so if I am missing something please let me know.

thank you for your time.

Comment: if it's a collection of ids, you could use a where in clause

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I really had no clue what I was doing. what you gotta do is convert a JSON object to an array and loop thrugy the array.

it should look something like this.(this example comes from w3 schools)

```
$jsonobj = '{"Peter":35,"Ben":37,"Joe":43}';

$arr = json_decode($jsonobj, true);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_json.asp

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you,

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
$resoponse = array();
$array_push = array();
// foreach($value as $id){
    $sql = "SELECT id, header, body FROM `messages` WHERE id= ?";
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        $response['id'] = $row ['id'];
        $response['header'] = $row ['header'];
        $response['body'] = $row ['body'];
        $array_push[] = $response; 
    }
    $stmt->close();
// }

$return = array("resoponse"=>array("check"=>"check"),"code"=>$array_push);

return json_encode($return);
```

Comment: initialise the array_push varriable before the starting the foreach loop $array_push = array();

Comment: Why not just `$array_push[] = $row;`?